# Can I use Dynamic Layer MapService on the client side using ArcGIS Online hosted weblayer?

Tags: arcgis-runtime, dynamic-layer

I'm developing a native android application using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android. All layers are hosted in AGOL organizational account as feature layers and web layers.

Is is possible to use Dynamic Layer Map Service to render layers on client side ?